# using "reactive native" with our existing code

Tags: android, ios, native, reactive

I wrote my app using native method, currently I want to use reactive native in our further development to avoid writing two copies of code for iOS and Android.

The problem is we can't completely rewrite all the code, we want to replace the project piece by piece.

So I am wondering if I can write some views of my project using reactive native and others remain native code that we have used a long time.

If this is possible, is there any existing tutorial about how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep your originally written native code via native modules. You can port your current project pieces by pieces to native modules, then let React-Native have access to it.

I guess best option is, start a new React-Native project and make it access your native modules, you won't have to rewrite everything then.

Here is more info for [Android](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) and [iOS](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is official documentation to this. Checkout:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html